# What video conferencing software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

There 're somebody i want to talk with him in a video conference in Ubuntu, how can i do that?

Comment: If its person to person video chat I recommend google with empathy/pidgin or video/voice plugin

Comment: This question was: "Video conference in ubutnu". It was edited by Jorge Castro changing it to "What video conferencing software is available?". This way, the answers from people may be misunderstood by voters because of "Video Conference in Ubuntu" may refer to a way on how to perform that task, which can evenly be achieved by broadcasting a webcam for the convenience of the participants. Somehow, Jorge Castro changed the sense of the question to the meaning of a specific software for the task, which limits the possibilities and makes people to down vote given answers. For your consideration.

Answer (score 6):

### Skype:

You can use Skype, which fully supports video conferencing and other useful features, such as screen sharing. http://www.skype.com/download

### aMSN

Even when aMSN is able to perform video conferencing, recently it is a difficult task as there are several changes in the MSN services and the way that it handles video connections.

In aMSN is it that easy as having installed Farsight, which is automatically installed in the majority of the cases and if not you will have enough information and a guide in order to install it.

Anyway it may fail as I have said in my initial words.

### Web Services

You may wish to give a chance to an online free video conference service, such as

### [Ubiqq](http://ubiqq.com/) http://ubiqq.com

[image]

Ubiqq uses a flash player based interface in order to gain access to both your webcam and microphone and allows the same in your contact's side.

A whole thread about how to make these online services to work is fully documented [right here](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=4998). Just in case that you can't make it work out of the box.

Good luck!

Comment: Skype is my choice..

Comment: And how does your comment lead to find a solution for this question @Roland Taylor? Dare to post your own answer. Don't drop reviews on mine. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't attack you........................

Comment: Me neither...... Oh... the message... It's my signature, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

[**OpenMeeting**](http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/)

> OpenMeetings is a free browser-based software that allows you to set up instantly a conference in the Web. You can use your microphone or webcam, share documents on a white board, share your screen or record meetings. It is available as hosted service or you download and install a package on your server with no limitations in usage or users.

Answer (score 1):

[Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/)

As their website says

> Ekiga (formerly known as GnomeMeeting) is an open source SoftPhone, Video Conferencing and Instant Messenger application over the Internet.
>
> It supports HD sound quality and video up to DVD size and quality.
>
> It is interoperable with many other standard compliant software, hardware and service providers as it uses both the major telephony standards (SIP and H.323).

Can be installed from the Software Center or using

```
sudo apt-get install ekiga
```

Answer (score 1):

Google hangouts offers screen sharing and group meetings (unlike skype which you have to pay for groups).  Everything is supported within the browser so very easy to install and collaborate with users of various OS and technical savvy.

https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1660627?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Reflap](http://www.reflap.com). It's web based so you won't need to download anything and it supports video conferencing with up to 5 video streams at the time. Also each user has a call address so you can get called by anyone that has your [call address](http://www.reflap.com/call-address) like your phone number.

Answer (score 0):

BigBlueButton is really fine, it is a great open source technology. I’m currently working at TALCOD (French Open source and Web agency), and all the customers seem satisfied with the solutions and videoconferencing rooms that we base on BigBlueButton. I do believe that open source solutions have a bright future. Maybe you could be interested in this software.

Answer (score -1):

GoMeetNow (http://www.gomeetnow.com) offers reliable, quality multi-point video conferencing despite platforms. It is full-featured and cost-effective and also listed in TOP 5 this year by Publicare. FYR, http://www.webconferencing-test.com/en/webconferencing_top5/webconference_compact_results.html.