# High quality software video telephony

Tags: networking, ssh, video, sip

I am trying to find a way to establish a high quality video phone connection between two kubuntu computers. One of the computers will be behind a firewall at a fixed IP but an ssh-port can be opened to it such that direct connections can be established in principle.

Skype or Google phone did not give me satisfying results so-far, even if the connection speed should have been high enough.

Are there any free sip-providers which support video telephony such that it can be set up with kubuntu soft phones? Or is there a way to make calls directly through an ssh-tunnel? Both computers can be set up with required software and it is not an issue to be able to call other devices or people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the pre installed `empathy` messaging cliant, it can do video calls based on, Google Talk, Jabber and sip.

Noticed you have Kubuntu so

```
sudo apt-get install empathy
```

There is also,ekiga,it has a good review in software center, here is its description

> H.323 and SIP compatible videoconferencing and VoIP/IP-Telephony
>   application that allows you to make audio and video calls to remote
>   users with H.323 hardware or software (such as Microsoft Netmeeting)
>   as well as SIP endpoints.
>
> It supports all modern videoconferencing features, such as contact
>   roster, presence status, high-quality audio and video codecs, various
>   video resolutions, registering to an LDAP directory, gatekeeper
>   support, making multi-user conference calls using an external MCU,
>   using modern Quicknet telephony cards, and making PC-To-Phone calls.
>
> Evolution plugin is in ekiga-plugin-evolution package

[Install from here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ekiga/) or

```
sudo apt-get install ekiga
```

[Also see this question for many suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30693/what-video-conferencing-software-is-available). (I did not flag as a dupe as the other question is 4 years old)

Comment: Ok. I assume Google Talk would give me the same poor quality as I experienced it before.  But I could try with sip. Something there I do not understand is whether video with sip poses requirements for the sip-provider or is it rather that the endpoints need to support the same standard? I didn't get sip to work with video so-far but have not tried empathy.

Comment: Sorry did you want an actual service provider as a posed to a client for calls ?

Comment: No, I just need a working combination of both. For now I do not have one where sip works with video (and I do not know the precise reason why it does not).

Comment: See how it goes with empathy and post back if you have issues, I will help you to get it going